# 'any' or 'any other'

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

1- Sachin Tendulkar has earned more reputation than any other cricketer has ever done is history.

2- Sachin Tendulkar has earned more reputation than any cricketer has ever done is history.

Comment: By "more reputation", do you mean "a better reputation"?  And by "is history", I think you mean "**in** history".

Comment: @rjpond yes. Can you tell me which one I shoud use in the sentence: 'any' or 'any other'?

Comment: Fiodor has responded to you below.  If Sachin Tendulkar is a cricketer, it makes more sense to say "any other" - although in practice, most people will take "any" to mean the same thing.  If he isn't a cricketer, you must say "any".

Answer (score 3):

Both uses are correct, but they mean something different.

The first sentence means that Sachin Tendulkar is a cricketer (more reputable that other cricketers).

The second sentence means that Sachin Tendulkar is not a cricketer himself, but is more reputable than all cricketers.

Most likely, though, what you mean is closer to the first sentence. I personally can't think of a context in which you would use the second one.

That being said, in other situations it might be appropriate, for example:

> This dictator is more powerful than any president in the world